# Error while saving date in mongodb using MongoOperations Spring Java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, date, mongotemplate

I need to save json object in mongodb having dates, here is sample json:

```
{
 "modifiedon": {
 "$dateFromString": {
     "dateString": "2017-02-08T12:10:40.787"
  }
},
"modifiedby": "ramsha-GRM1 Ambreen",
"id": 537
}
```

I expect 'modifiedOn' value should save as

```
"modifiedon": ISODate("2017-02-08T12:10:40.78")
```

Here is a code to insert json into mongodb using java

```
String json = {<JSONVALUE>};
mongoOperations.insert(json,"risk");
```

But MongoOperations save JSON without process $dateFromString which is a date formatted in MongoDB. Any leads are highly appreciated thanks

Comment: [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/index.html) is an aggregation operator - it is not to be used within the data / JSON being saved. Please include the code you are using to save the data.

Comment: @prasad_ i have added code piece which inserts JSON into mongodb

Comment: [MongoTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html) doesn't have an `insert` method that takes a JSON as a parameter.

Comment: You can look for `MongoTemplate#insert` usage examples in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hit an trial above issue has been resolved by modifying input JSON object as

`{ "modifiedon": { "$date": "2020-09-30T11:32:58.000Z" }, "modifiedby": "ramsha-GRM1 Ambreen", "id": 229 }`

AND it is saved in MongoDB as date object and I am able to query against date